# tcolorbox: How to read out values like left, right,

Tags: tcolorbox, pgfkeys

How can I read out values like `left, right,..., boxsep`? 
I tried `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/left}`. What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[left=22pt]
The left skip was setted to: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/left}  ?
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here a new command `\pgfkeysLastValueOf{<full key>}` is provided. You can use `\pgfkeysLastValueOf{/tcb/left}` to retrieve the current (or, most recently passed) value of `/tcb/left`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\pgfkeys@unpack
  {\pgfkeys@case@one}
  { 
    \pgfkeyslet{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@last}{\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}%
    \pgfkeys@case@one
  }
  {}{\fail}

\def\pgfkeysLastValueOf#1{\csname pgfk@#1/.@last\endcsname}
\makeatother

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[left=22pt]
    The left skip was set to: \pgfkeysLastValueOf{/tcb/left}\par
    The right skip was set to: \pgfkeysLastValueOf{/tcb/right}\par
    The boxsep was set to: \pgfkeysLastValueOf{/tcb/boxsep}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Note that to make the patching work for keys initially set when loading `tcolorbox`, you have to load `pgfkeys` and patch it before `tcolorbox` is loaded.

[image]

#### Update: a refined version, with new handler `.last value` introduced

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%% patch pgfkeys to store current value in subkey ".@last"
\makeatletter
% value passed to keys that execute commands
\xpatchcmd\pgfkeys@case@one
  {\pgfkeysgetvalue}
  {\pgfkeyslet{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@last}{\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}
   \pgfkeysgetvalue}
  {}{\fail}

% value passed to keys that store values
\xpatchcmd\pgfkeys@case@two@extern
  {\else}
  {\else
   \pgfkeyslet{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.@last}{\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}}
  {}{\fail}

% value passed to keys that when key is defined by ".initial"
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.initial/.code=%
  % in handlered key eg "/tcb/xleft/.initial",
  %   \pgfkeyscurrentkey  == "/tcb/xleft/.initial"
  %   \pgfkeyscurrentpath == "/tcb/xleft"
  \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{}
    % only update ".@last" if this key is not previously defined by ".code"
    {\pgfkeyslet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@last}{\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}}%
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{#1}}
\makeatother


\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}


% user interface: fully expandable command
\def\pgfkeysLastValueOf#1{\csname pgfk@#1/.@last\endcsname}

% user interface: handler
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.last value/.code={%
  \pgfkeysLastValueOf{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tcblisting}{left=22pt}
    The left skip was set to: \pgfkeysLastValueOf{/tcb/left}\par
    The right skip was set to: \pgfkeysLastValueOf{/tcb/right}\par
    The boxsep was set to: \tcbset{boxsep/.last value}
  \end{tcblisting}
  
  \begin{tcblisting}{}
    \tcbset{xkey/.store in=\myxkey, xkey=xvalue}
    \tcbset{xkey/.initial=init value}
    
    \tcbset{xkey/.last value} % should be "xvalue", not "init value"
  \end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks good. You could use it to contact the author. He also converted the various colors of a box into easy-to-use keys (as far as I know, that was not possible in earlier versions).

Comment: @cis That's done by providing a new handler `.colorlet` defined as `\pgfkeys{/handlers/.colorlet/.code=\pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\colorlet{#1}{##1}}}`.

Comment: @cis I added a refined version.

Comment: This "minted"-stuff does not run at mine, something with python I think. Whatever, I can compile it with normal `listings`, if I say `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`, not `\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}`

Comment: @cis The `minted`-stuff is just for better code highlighting, hence is totally avoidable. `minted` package need python library `pygments`. By using `tcolorbox`'s package options `most`, `listings` package is used for highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

In `tcolorbox` v4.41, both keys [`/tcb/left`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/9858cec2254aab25a099d919e158a05132abab31/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty#L251) and [`/tcb/right`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/9858cec2254aab25a099d919e158a05132abab31/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty#L256) are defined as a style key, hence their values are just passed to other keys, and never stored (in anything directly related to those two keys themselves).

```tex
\tcbset{
  left/.style={lefttitle=#1,leftupper=#1,leftlower=#1},
  right/.style={righttitle=#1,rightupper=#1,rightlower=#1},
}
```

Key [`/tcb/boxsep`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/9858cec2254aab25a099d919e158a05132abab31/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty#L202) is defined by

```tex
\tcbset{
  boxsep/.store in=\kvtcb@boxsep,
}
```

hence its value is stored in `\kvtcb@boxsep`. The definition (or "value") of full key `/tcb/boxsep/.@cmd` do contains `\kvtcb@boxsep`, though in an indirect way:

```tex
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tcb/boxsep/.@cmd}\temp \meaning\temp
% gives
% \long macro:#1\pgfeov ->\def \kvtcb@boxsep {#1}
```

In general, currently there is no easy and consistent way to retrieve the value most recently passed to a key defined by `pgfkeys`. Roughly speaking, `\pgfkeysvalueof` can only retrieve values, rather than macros, from keys that store values, see `pgfmanual` v3.1.6a, sec. 87.3.4. But most keys provided by packages are handled keys, see sec. 87.3.5 from the same manual.

Comment: So, there is no way to read out these "22pt"?

Comment: @cis Unless one patches `pgfkeys` to add new utilities to it.

Comment: Mmmh, but something must be possible there; e.g. I save tcb/left in a new key and use global, edef. I don't know, unfortunately I do not get it.

Comment: Ah, I see you posted a new answer.