# get value of tcolorbox options

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I tried to get value from `tcolorbox`'s option as the following example shows, but failed. Am I missing something?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.5\textwidth]
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/width}%This typeset nothing.
  \rule{0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/width}}{5pt} %This causes error.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565262

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z Thank you. The method in the answer provided in the link you give is to change the macro of `pgf`. I don't want to do that. No other better ways?

Comment: No better ways. `\pgfkeysvalueof` works only for keys that are defined by handler `/.initial`, but most `tcolorbox` options are defined by handler `/.code` and friends. From `tcolorbox` source code, `\kvtcb@width` holds the "value" of `/tcb/width`, either set by user or computed from other settings.